# Android- How to find Safari Version used in Webview

Tags: android

How Can I check which version of Safari is being used by webview?

I know I can check this by using useragent

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; ADR6400L 4G Build/FRG83D) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Here Version/4.0 will be version number.

But can we check it using code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no version of Safari as Android doesn't use Safari.
If you want to know which WebView version is used (which WebKit) you can try that by using the UserAgent.

UPDATE: To receive your UserAgentString programatically use this:

```
WebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString()
```

Comment: Can I somehow directly fetch Safari Version through code, rather then parsing the user agent String?